# Excel formula for conditional summation based on string

Tags: string, excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I have a column of data that looks something like this:

Row A   B  C  D
    100 50 0  A->B
    50 0 100  C->A
    75  75 0  B->A
etc

I want to enter a formula in a single cell that sums across the rows A to C only if the first letter in column D is "A", but for the range e.g. A2:C10000.

Is this possible?

As things stand, I have dabbled with the LEFT() function but I cannot get it to work across a range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **SUMIF** formula to sum a single column where a cell in Column **D** starts with **A**.

```
=SUMIF($D$2:$D$10000,"A*",$A$2:$A$10000)
```

To get all three columns repeat the formula three times.

```
=SUMIF($D$2:$D$10000,"A*",$A$2:$A$10000)+SUMIF($D$2:$D$10000,"A*",$B$2:$B$10000)+SUMIF($D$2:$D$10000,"A*",$C$2:$C$10000)
```